# Fast way to find the next multiple of a number

Tags: objective-c, c, math

I need to find the first multiple for a number starting from a base number. For example: The first multiple of 3 from 7 is 9. My first attempt was to do this:

```
multiple = baseNumber
while(multiple%number !=0 )
    multiple++
```

At the end, "multiple" will have the first multiple of `number` after `baseNumber`. The problem is that when `number` becomes too large, the number of iterations becomes too many. So my question is: is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: You might be better off asking this at the Mathematics Stack Exchange. You might also want to provide a clearer or more rigorous definition of what you mean by multiple of a number.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If everything is guaranteed to be positive, try

```
multiple = baseNumber + number - 1;
multiple -= (multiple % number);
```

That does it in constant time.

First, we add `number - 1` to make sure that we have a number at least as large as the next multiple but smaller than the one after that. Then we subtract the remainder of the division by `number` to make sure we have the desired multiple.

If `baseNumber` can be negative (but `number` still positive), we face the problem that `multiple % number` may be negative if `multiple < 0`, so the above could skip a multiple of `number`. To avoid that, we can use e.g.

```
remainder = multiple % number;
if (remainder < 0) remainder += number;
multiple -= remainder;
```

If branching is too expensive, we can avoid the `if` at the cost of two divisions instead of one,

```
multiple -= (number + (multiple % number)) % number;
```

Generally, the `if` seems preferable, though.

If `number` can be negative, replace it with its absolute value first.

Note: The above returns, as the original code does, `baseNumber` if that is already a multiple of `number`. If that isn't desired, remove the `- 1` in the first line.

Comment: I don't think this is right, assuming that the next multiple greater than `baseNumber` is required.  Consider `baseNumber=6, number=3`; you'll get 6.  More generally, I think this will fail whenever `number` divides `baseNumber`.

Comment: I went by OP's code that also returns `baseNumber` if that is already a multiple. But I'll add a note concerning this, thanks.

Comment: @DSM If that's the case, then all you have to do is remove the "-1", and you should be fine.

Comment: @DanielFischer: typo mutliple => multiple

Comment: @Ehouarn Thanks, fixed.

Comment: This simple and efficient approach might produce unexpected results if `baseNumber` is negative.

Comment: Good point @chqrlie, I didn't think of negative numbers. Fortunately, `((base/number)+1)*number` has the same problem, so I don't need to feel too bad for overlooking that.

Answer (score 5):

try this (Requires INTEGER division):

```
multiple = ((base/number) + 1) * number;
```

7/3 = 2.   3*(2+1) = 9.

You have an edge case where the `baseNumber` already is a multiple of `number`, which you will have to test using the modulus operation.

Comment: Doh.  I pretty much repeated your answer.  But don't you need a floor function after base/number?

Comment: Ah.  So there's a REASON you put words in bold.

Comment: That was am edit after your comment.  No, you didn't miss it on the first pass.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need a loop?

multiple = (floor(number/baseNumber)+1)*baseNumber

Answer (score 0):

```
 while(multiple * number < baseNumber)
      multiple++;
```

so for baseNumber = 3, number = 7, your multiple is 3;

though, something tells me bignums are about to show up in here.

Comment: I feel like this runs into the same problem as what the OP had. Suppose `number` is something like 2 and baseNumber is 1 billion. You don't want to have to check all the multiples of 2 up to 1 billion.

Comment: in that case this is more of math question then... i know there's a formula for that. gotta look up my old crypto notes i guess....